# Creating valid mail enabled contacts without using Exchange specific cmdlets

Tags: active-directory, exchange, powershell, exchange-2013

I have written a powershell script to routinely process and import a large (over 70k) amount of contacts into an Exchange environment. The script works fine but I would like to speed it up if possible. The most time consuming parts used to be importing and exporting the data.

I was able to cut down a lot of the processing time by removing most of the dependencies on Exchange 2013 cmdlets. For example, using the "native" Get-ADObject cmdlet to extract the data instead of a combination of the Exchange specific Get-MailContact and Get-Contact I was able to reduce the processing time by a factor of 10.

The command looks like this:

```
$result = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectClass=contact)" -searchBase "$OU"  -ResultPageSize 100 -property GivenName, SN, DisplayName, Department, physicalDeliveryOfficeName , telephoneNumber, mailnickname, targetaddress |  select @{ label="Email"; Expression={ ($_.targetaddress -replace "^SMTP:","").tostring().Tolower().Trim() }}, @{ N="Alias"; E={ $_.mailnickname} }, @{ N="FirstName"; E={ $_.GivenName} }, @{ N="LastName"; E={ $_.SN} }, DisplayName,  @{ N="Office"; E={ $_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName} } , Department, @{ N="Phone"; E={ $_.telephoneNumber} }
```

Now I would like to be able to do the opposite, to create the contacts. That is, create a mail enabled contact without using Exchange specific cmdlets. I managed to create a contact using this command:

```
$Attributes = @{'displayName' = $displayname; 'GivenName' = $first; 'SN' = $last; 'Department' = $department; 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' = $office; 'telephoneNumber' = $phone; 'mail' = $email; 'mailnickname' = $alias; 'targetaddress' = $email}

New-AdObject -Type Contact -Name $displayname -Path $OU -OtherAttributes $Attributes -whatif
```

However, although the object is apparently created correctly, it does not show up among the contacts on Exchange. The only  way so far I have been able to achieve this is to run the "Enable-MailContact" cmdlet on the object after creation, which defeats the purpose of not using Exchange cmdlets in the process.

So my question is, does anybody know if there is a way to create a functional mail enabled contact using only the New-ADObject cmdlet and without relying on Exchange specific cmdlets ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the crucial missing item was the "showinaddressbook" property.

This article explains how it works: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/253828

> The *showInAddressBook* attribute has two purposes. The first is to
>   let people see the entry listed in the address list by means of
>   Messaging Application Programming Interface (MAPI) client, such as
>   Microsoft Outlook. The second purpose is to allow users to "resolve a
>   name" on a MAPI client.

Even though the article refers to the Recipient Update Service (RUS) which does not exist anymore since Exchange 2007, I guess the underlying process for mail enabling an object is still the same.

So basically to create a mail-enabled contact without using the Exchange 2013 cmdlets I did something like this:

```
$alias = "ADDR-00001"
$email = "jdoe@somewhere.com"
$first = "Joe"
$last = "Doe"
$displayname = "DOE Joe"
$department = "My Dept."
$office = "My Office"
$phone = "55554448934"
$proxyAddresses = "SMTP:jdoe@somewhere.com"
$DestinationOU = "OU=contact,OU=example,DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com"
$AddressBook = "CN=Default Global Address List,CN=All Global Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=Example-Org,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com","CN=All Contacts,CN=All Address Lists,CN=Address Lists Container,CN=Example-Org,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com"

$Attributes = @{'displayName' = $displayname; 'GivenName' = $first; 'SN' = $last; 'Department' = $department; 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName' = $office; 'telephoneNumber' = $phone; 'mail' = $email; 'mailnickname' = $alias; 'targetaddress' = $email; 'proxyAddresses' = $proxyAddresses; 'showinaddressbook' = $AddressBook;}

New-AdObject -Type Contact -Name $displayname -Path $DestinationOU -OtherAttributes $Attributes
```

The resulting object still does not have the `LegacyExchangeDN` value and it has a peculiar `ExchangeVersion` but the `AddressListMembership` property is now populated.

```
Get-Mailcontact "jdoe@somewhere.com" | select displayName, RecipientType, LegacyExchangeDN, ExchangeVersion, AddressListMembership| fl

DisplayName           : DOE Joe
RecipientType         : MailContact
LegacyExchangeDN      :
ExchangeVersion       : 0.0 (6.5.6500.0)
AddressListMembership : {\All Contacts, \Default Global Address List}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be it is missing the proxyAddresses attribute.  You can check it AD Users and Computers to see the attributes that were added by the Enable-MailContact attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the `proxyAddresses` attribute and I might be on the right track but still no cigar. By comparing two contacts created one with the Exchange cmdlets and one with the `New-AdObject` cmdlet, I notice that the following attributes are empty in the second case: `AddressListMembership`, `LegacyExchangeDN`, `UMDtmfMap`. Also, the attribute `ExchangeVersion` is set to `0.1 (8.0.535.0)` for contacts created by Exchange itself and `0.0 (6.5.6500.0)` for contacts created by `New-AdObject`. I will do some more tests.

Comment: Looks like it would also need legacyExchangeDN and msExchRecipientDisplayType = 6 (RemoteMailUser).